# How to display progress dialog before the app or activity loads?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, progressdialog

I have a startup activity, this is a launcher activity, in this I have intent for the sliding activity this is to show the walk through screens.

Now When I run the app it takes few seconds to start the sliding activity. I want to show a progress dialog till the sliding activity starts.

How can I do this?

StartUp activity:

```
    public class StartUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    boolean isUserFirstTime,login;
    public static String PREF_USER_FIRST_TIME;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        isUserFirstTime = Boolean.valueOf(Utils.readSharedSetting(StartUpActivity.this, PREF_USER_FIRST_TIME, "true"));
        Intent introIntent = new Intent(StartUpActivity.this, SlidingActivity.class);
        introIntent.putExtra(PREF_USER_FIRST_TIME, isUserFirstTime);


        ProgressDialog dialog=new ProgressDialog(StartUpActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Welcome to Mea Vita, please wait till the app loads.");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(false);
        dialog.show();


        startActivity(new Intent(StartUpActivity.this,SlidingActivity.class));
        dialog.hide();

    }

}
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Is it not showing the `ProgressDialog`?

Comment: `app it takes few seconds to start the sliding activity` are you doing any operation for few seconds..? or simple you want to hold user for few seconds.

Comment: I am not doing anything, as it takes time to run to make user interactive I want to show the dialog. @skadoosh

Comment: no  it is not showing the diaog. @DevendraSingh

Comment: according to your code.. actually its showing the dialog.. and why u cant see that - when it shows next moment it disappears (dialog.hide())..

Comment: try to hide dialog and start activity after few seconds of StartUpActivity  launch..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok if you want show a dialog for 1 or 2 seconds you can use `Handler` class.like

```
 ProgressDialog dialog=new ProgressDialog(StartUpActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Welcome to Mea Vita, please wait till the app loads.");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(false);
        dialog.show();
```

this is as your `ProgressDialog`
write this code for the delay of 1 second or 2 seconds.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Here you can send the extras.
            Intent i = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

            // close this activity
            finish();
        }
    }, 2000);
```